# Preg_match want only the first brackets

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

Goodday,

I have this script beneath to recognize the first tag ([Test1])
But all it does with the uri I have right now is take the first bracket and the last one,
so the output is "**Test1] Title [Test9**"

I want the output to be "**Test1**". I already tried to change the preg_match, but it seems I'm not getting what I want.
Hope someone can help me to get on the right path.

```
<?php
$uri = "[Test1] Title [Test9].jpg";
$str = "'".$uri."'";
if (preg_match('/\[([^\)]+)\]/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "[".$matches[1]."]";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the `UNGREEDY` flag, just add `/pattern/U` on your `preg_match_all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use '?' sign in order to get the ungreedy matches:

```
<?php
$uri = "[Test1] Title [Test9].jpg";
$str = "'".$uri."'";
if (preg_match('/\[(.+?)\]/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "[".$matches[1]."]";
}
```

[test it online](http://ideone.com/OOInA)

Comment: This is the one I wanted. Thanks!